# Error con la libreria interop.word.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente error al usar la librería `interop.word.dll`.
Alguien puede ayudarme a solucionarlo?

> [UnauthorizedAccessException]: Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due
>   to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType
>   objectType)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   serverType)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType
>   serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
>          at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>          at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>          at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>          at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
>          at SGPJ.DescargarArchivo.Merge(String[] filesToMerge, String outputFilename, Boolean insertPageBreaks, String documentTemplate,
>   String nsec_aop, DataTable tblRequisitos)
>          at SGPJ.DescargarArchivo.GenerarProtocolo3(String nsecAop)
>          at SGPJ.DescargarArchivo.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 0):

a mi lo siguiente me resulto para un error del tipo acceso denegado con la misma librería:

Desde Ejecutar (Win + R) colocar DCOMCNFG (lo que abre la interfaz de servicios de componentes) y luego realizar estos pasos:

1) Luego ir a Raíz de Consola > Servicios de Componentes > Equipos, click derecho en Mi PC, y seleccionar Propiedades.

2) Después en la pestaña Seguridad COM > Permisos de inicio y activación, elegir "Editar valores predeterminados"

3) Agregar el usuario con el que se ejecuta la aplicacion, por ejemplo si usas asp.net alojado en IIS, agregas el usuario IIS_IUSRS o el servicio con el que se ejecute.

4) Y finalmente en los permisos, tildar ejecucion local y activacion local.

Con esto yo no tuve mas problemas de acceso denegado con las librerias de Office.

Saludos!